# How to send an email using shell script with content type equals to multipart/mixed

Tags: python, shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting I want to send an email with an attachment. I am getting the mail content as below.

**Mail Content**

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============810XXX3964=="\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nMessage-Id: <15XXXX83629.6472.166383011XXXX.a7cwXXXXH02@migrated>\nX-Original-From: Administrator <admin@example.com>\nCC: \nTo: pqr@gtech.com\nFrom: Administrator <abc@gmail.com.com>\nX-Frappe-Site: http://server:9010\nDate: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 05:50:36 -0000\nReply-To: admin@example.com\nBcc: \nSubject: BIS: BMR/014 Test\n\n--===============8102977676867523964==\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;\n boundary="===============1984896067029127512=="\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n\n--===============1984896067029127512==\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n\n  =\n\n\n  =\n\n  =\n\n\n> On 3rd January 2020, 4:33pm, admin@example.com wrote:\n\n>\n\n> 
-- Several texts in between hence not mentioned all the content
</table>\n\t\t\t</td>\n\t\t</tr>\n\t</table>\n</body>\n\n</html>\n\n--===============1XXX9127512==--\n\n--===============8102977676867523964==--\n"
```

I tried below shell script in python.

```
os.popen('echo "{0}" | mail -s "{1}" -a "From: {2}" {3}'.format(message, subject, frappe.session.user_email, recipients))
```

It is working when we are sending plain text messages. But what to do in case of **Multipart/Mixed content**

Also, Tried mailx but it also not works.

```
mailx -a "above mail content"
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending mails, the `mail` program is a "user friendly" wrapper over a lower level program. Long story made short, mail assumes that what you a giving it is a text message and does it best to encode it so that the recipient will still sees it in the same *text* format that it receives. In particular, it assumes that adding header lines is its jobs, not yours...

Here you have already formatted the mail, including the header lines, so you do not want that the sending program touches anything. So you do not want to use mail but the lower level program which is generally called `sendmail`. Use `man sendmail` on your system to know more...